# Keep two, skip two in Python list

Tags: python, list, indexing

I have a Python list

```
num_list = list(range(1,33))
```

And need every other pair of numbers in the list, like this:

```
[1, 2, 5, 6, 9, 10 ... ]
```

I've figured out how to exclude certain indices from the list, like this

```
num_list[2::3]

> [3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30]
```

but haven't figured out how to allow it to capture two indices at a time.

Comment: Maybe: `[i for i in range(1,33) if i%4 != 0 and i%4 != 3]` if it's always a consecutive sequence from 1 to N.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just slice the list twice and then sort it.

```
sorted(num_list[0::4]+num_list[1::4])
```

Answer (score 9):

You could use `enumerate`, then filter the index mathematically:

```
[v for i, v in enumerate(num_list) if i % 4 < 2]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this with just one slice operation. You could do something like

```py
[num_list[j] for i in range(0, len(num_list), 4) for j in (i, i+1)]
```

Edit: another option is this:

```py
[x for i in range(0, len(num_list), 4) for x in num_list[i:i+2]]
```

and yet another (lazy) option is

```
def keep_two_skip_two(it):
    it = iter(it)
    try:
        while True:
            yield next(it)
            yield next(it)
            next(it)
            next(it)
    except StopIteration:
        return

list(keep_two_skip_two(num_list))
```

Comment: Why is the last option lazy? It just seems needlessly verbose.

Comment: It will work for arbitrary iterators, rather than just lists.

Comment: "Lazy", not as in "for lazy programmers", but as in "for lazy (even infinite) iterators"

Comment: "Lazy" as in it will be executed for each iteration and not for all of the list in one go.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution for your case would be a list comprehension combined with slicing and zip. Slicing only extracts the needed values, zips combines them together as pairs, and in the list comprehension, you can iterate over the pairs to form the final output. In code, that reads ,like

```py
[p for pairs in zip(num_list[::4],num_list[1::4]) for p in pairs]
```

Answer (score 3):

You could make something a little bit more generic depending on what your pattern looks like. Instead of using an index based condition, you could apply a mask. e.g.

```
mask = [1, 1, 0, 0]
```

To create the mask where the values repeat such that it is the same length of your data, you can `zip` the data alongside `itertools.cycle(m)`. Example:

```
import itertools


def filter_mask(data, mask):
    return [d for d, m in zip(data, itertools.cycle(mask)) if m]
```

Or use compress as [@KellyBundy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12671057/kelly-bundy) suggests!

```
def filter_mask(data, mask):
    return list(itertools.compress(data, itertools.cycle(mask)))
```

Example

```
>>> data = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> filter_mask(data, mask=[1, 0])
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
>>> filter_mask(data, mask=[0, 1])
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
>>> filter_mask(data, mask=[1, 1, 0, 0])
[0, 1, 4, 5, 8, 9]
>>> filter_mask(data, mask=[1, 0, 1, 1, 0])
[0, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10]
```

Comment: Ah, you beat me to `cycle`, but at least I didn't reinvent `compress` :-P

Comment: @KellyBundy Ah, lol. I didn't even know about that one!

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 1:** Using two excludes:

```
del num_list[2::4]
del num_list[2::3]
```

Now your list is:

```
[1, 2, 5, 6, 9, 10, 13, 14, 17, 18, 21, 22, 25, 26, 29, 30]
```

**Solution 2:** Using `compress` and `cycle` from `itertools`:

```
list(compress(num_list, cycle([True, True, False, False]))))
```

Shorter version:

```
[*compress(num_list, cycle([1, 1, 0, 0]))]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using different `range` objects for two generators:

```
>>> [x for i in range(1,33,4) for x in range(i, i+2)]
[1, 2, 5, 6, 9, 10, 13, 14, 17, 18, 21, 22, 25, 26, 29, 30]
```

A lazy version that only generates the 2-element ranges on demand:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> x = chain.from_iterable(range(i, i+2) for i in range(1,33,4))
>>> list(x)
[1, 2, 5, 6, 9, 10, 13, 14, 17, 18, 21, 22, 25, 26, 29, 30]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a functional way to achieve this using [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) along with [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) on your *sliced* lists as:

```
>>> num_list = list(range(1,33))
>>> from itertools import chain

>>> list(chain.from_iterable(zip(num_list[::4], num_list[1::4])))
[1, 2, 5, 6, 9, 10, 13, 14, 17, 18, 21, 22, 25, 26, 29, 30]
```