# python move every second pair of letters to a new line in a multi line document

Tags: python, text, format

So I have a multi line text file,

```
soeqashriabsokxz
gajqjrvtxwxigbuy
iyhhzvjdflwybdbx
cycnqfptcuknuwlt
```

and I would like to take every second pair of letters
and make a new line under each line from those letters

```
soasiaok
eqhrbsxz
gajrxwgb 
jqvtxiuy
iyzvflbd 
hhjdwybx
cyqfcuuw 
cnptknlt
```

does anybody ahve any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following:

```py
from itertools import chain

with open('in.txt') as input_file, open('out.txt', 'w') as output_file:
  for line in input_file:
    line = line.rstrip() # remove trailing newline

    first_line = ''.join(chain.from_iterable(zip(line[0::4], line[1::4])))
    second_line = ''.join(chain.from_iterable(zip(line[2::4], line[3::4])))

    output_file.write(first_line + '\n')
    output_file.write(second_line + '\n')
```

This question uses methods described in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70626961/17769815) and extends them to strings.

In essence, we use string slicing to read the first and second character into a tuple. Then, we skip to the fifth and sixth character, and read those into another tuple. We then chain all of these tuples into an iterable using `chain.from_iterable()` and then read it out into a string using `''.join()`.

We do the same for the second line, except we start at the third and fourth characters in the line rather than the first and second.

When `in.txt` is the file given, `out.txt` is:

```
soasiaok
eqhrbsxz
gajrxwgb
jqvtxiuy
iyzvflbd
hhjdwybx
cyqfcuuw
cnptknlt
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `chunks` recipe from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks):

```
def chunks(lst, n):
    """Yield successive n-sized chunks from lst."""
    for i in range(0, len(lst), n):
        yield lst[i:i + n]

chopped = [chunks(list(chunks(line, 2)), 2) for line in lines]
chopped = [zip(*c) for c in chopped]
for (row1parts, row2parts) in chopped:
    print(''.join(row1parts))
    print(''.join(row2parts))
```

For example:

```
lines = """
soeqashriabsokxz
gajqjrvtxwxigbuy
iyhhzvjdflwybdbx
cycnqfptcuknuwlt
""".strip().split()

def chunks(lst, n):
    for i in range(0, len(lst), n):
        yield lst[i:i + n]

chopped = [chunks(list(chunks(line, 2)), 2) for line in lines]
chopped = [zip(*c) for c in chopped]
for (row1parts, row2parts) in chopped:
    print(''.join(row1parts))
    print(''.join(row2parts))
```

```
soasiaok
eqhrbsxz
gajrxwgb
jqvtxiuy
iyzvflbd
hhjdwybx
cyqfcuuw
cnptknlt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a generator of tuples of chunks:

```
lines = '''soeqashriabsokxz
gajqjrvtxwxigbuy
iyhhzvjdflwybdbx
cycnqfptcuknuwlt'''.split()

def pairs(s, n=2, m=2):
    for i in range(0, len(s), n+m):
        yield (s[i:i+n], s[i+n:i+n+m])

for l in lines:
    # printing here for the example
    # but you can save to file
    print('\n'.join([''.join(e) for e in zip(*pairs(l))]))
```

Output:

```
soasiaok
eqhrbsxz
gajrxwgb
jqvtxiuy
iyzvflbd
hhjdwybx
cyqfcuuw
cnptknlt
```

##### generalization

Here is the generalization to split each line in an arbitrary number of lines with an arbitrary number of characters per line:

```
def pairs(s, k):
    x = 0
    for i in range(0, len(s), sum(k)):
        yield [s[x:(x:=x+e)] for e in k]

def split(lines, k=(2, 2)):
    for l in lines:
        chunks = zip(*pairs(l, k=k))
        print('\n'.join([''.join(e) for e in chunks]))
```

examples:

```
split(lines, k=(1,2,3))
sho
oerikx
qasabsz
gvg
ajtxbu
qjrwxiy
ijb
yhdfdb
hzvlwyx
cpu
yctcwl
nqfuknt

split(lines, k=(5,0,1))
soeqahriabokxz

ss
gajqjvtxwxgbuy

ri
iyhhzjdflwbdbx

vy
cycnqptcukuwlt

fn
```